# Google Tag Manager fails to load on Firefox Quantum

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-tag-manager

Since installing Firefox Quantum, I've noticed that Google Tag Manager is failing to load on some sites I manage. I can't seem to figure out why it's failing, the Firefox console reports the following error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source
“https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[GTM-CONTAINER-ID]”.
```

On Chrome and other browsers, it loads absolutely fine, but on Firefox Quantum, it just completely fails and is repeatable across many different sites.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue, or if there's a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem as well, and I think it's their new feature Tracking Protection.
And it somehow frees people from Google's GodEye lol

- Some news:

  - https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/11/12/firefox-to-offer-tracking-protection-for-all-in-its-next-update/
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection
- Official:

  - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tracking-protection